# how to create epic in jira- epics in jira

Tags: automation

scenario : We are in the integration testing phase . We would like to group all bugs in this phase on JIRA .

My problem : I wanted to create an epic called "testing phase" and group all bugs in the testing phase . But I also wanted to create a subgroup for "integration testing" and group all bugs in this integration testing phase . How do I do this .Can I use tasks under epic and do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The Epic issue type (and a few others) are added to a base JIRA installation when you install the "JIRA Agile" extension/plugin. None of the features (Epic Links, Epics filtering on backlogs, Epic burndown charts, etc) will work with any other issue type.

chrome